# Arduino vs Raspberry, Advantages And Disadvantes

Tags: programming, power, raspberrypi

I have done extensive research into the differences and here are the questions i have:

1. What is a micro controller and what differs it from the raspberry pi system
2. Why buy the Arduino when it is less powerful than the raspberry pi
3. What projects would either system be better for
4. Does Arduino run a full OS
5. Where is the best place to buy arduino and raspberry pi
6. What is the difference in the ad dons
7. Which has the most tutorials
8. What is the different's in power supply and usages
9. I know i'm asking this on a forum with arduino fans (There is no arduino vs raspberry pi forum) but opinions aside which is the best for beginners (I can program C++ and python as well as building hardware components)
10. What is the general price different overall including buying extra ad dons/shields

Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: This question is also on the Raspberry pi forum to ensure non baits answers: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43458/arduino-vs-raspberry-advantages-and-disadvantes

Comment: Cross-posting within Stack Exchange is not permitted. See: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/)

Comment: And here the answer is the same as the one to this question: "which is better, a car or a a pc?".. the answer is.. it depends! They are completely different systems, with completely different targets, completely different requirements (required electronics, user skills, environment...), It depends on your application. USUALLY simple = arduino, complicated = raspberry, interaction = both, but... it depends ;) The only "real" question is number 4, and its answer is NO, Arduino does not have an OS (you are writing the whole code, no layers between you and the hardware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Here is a great article about microcontrollers and how they differ from a full computer: http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/microcontroller1.htm 
tl;dr: A Raspberry Pi runs a full desktop OS (often Linux) and as such, can do most of the things a "typical" computer can do, such as browse the internet or install different programs. An Arduino, however, cannot do that. An Arduino can run one piece of software that you program to it (called a sketch in the Arduino world) and repeat that same program over and over.

2) They have different purposes. A Raspberry Pi is designed as a low-cost desktop computer that you can put anywhere, and also as a platform that is easy to put into different projects. An Arduino is better suited for attaching sensors to, controlling motors, etc.

3) see #2
Also, a Raspberry Pi is typically used when a GUI is wanted, or when more computing power is required. An Arduino is typically used for more real time things such as reading sensors or controlling LED's.

4) No, it does not. Arduino's run C++ compiled as machine code object files.

5) For the Raspberry Pi, Here is the list of official resellers: https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-b-plus/
For the arduino, it depends on what kind you're buying and where you live, there are many different styles.

6) As a general rule, Arduino's have more shields. But, a raspberry pi typically needs a screen, mouse, keyboard, etc. Everything a standard computer needs.

7) Entirely depends on what you're trying to do.

8) Both take a 5V input voltage. An Arduino can take up to a 20v input (again, depending on the model) whereas the Raspberry Pi can just be powered with 5v over USB.

9) Again, depends on what you're trying to do. A Raspberry Pi is "easier" to use, as it's a full computer.

Comment: Thank you very much i'm thankful for your answer i think the arduino is for me. I like more of the technical side of things :) and plus I've already got a pico itx setup which is very similar to the raspberry pi anyway. And hey the arduino forums seem to be nicer then the snobby raspberry pi fans :p